# Read .xlsx computed cell values using openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I am trying to read the values (not formulas) in a range of cells in a .xlsx file. If I include the data_only=True option in the call to load_workbook I get the error:

```
opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/_reader.py:296: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
```

If I leave out the data_only option then the load_workbook works fine but I get the formulas rather than the computed values. Is there a way for me to get the last computed values?

Comment: Does it have to be ````openpyxl````? Have you considered ````pandas.read_excel```` ?

Comment: Redox - Pandas uses openpyxl to read XLSX files!

Comment: That's only a warning telling you that there is something in the workbook that openpyxl doesn't know how to process. It has **nothing** to do with the `data_only`parameter.

Comment: It may only be a warning but the statement fails and I can’t read the file when data_only = true. Without data_only = True the script reads the cells but gets the formulas and not the values computed by the formulas.

Comment: Is it just the one xlsx file that has the issue? Are you able to post the file here (anonymised if necessary)?

Comment: I created what I thought would be a minimal failing case and to my surprise, it worked. I went back to the original file and it also worked. So I am at a loss as to how I managed to get that error message. I still get a warning message about the file suffix being deprecated but I assume I can ignore that.